# react native shuffle flat list array

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to add a button to shuffle an array, however when the page is loaded the flat list comes shuffled.

Here I have the array:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      deck: [
        { id: Math.random(), text: "0" }, 
        { id: Math.random(), text: "1" }, 
        { id: Math.random(), text: "2" }, 
        { id: Math.random(), text: "3" }, 
        { id: Math.random(), text: "4" }, 
        { id: Math.random(), text: "5" }, 
        { id: Math.random(), text: "6" }, 
        { id: Math.random(), text: "7" }, 
        { id: Math.random(), text: "8" }, 
        { id: Math.random(), text: "9" }, 
      ],
    };
  }
```

now the shuffle function

```
  shuffleDeck = (array) => {
    let i = array.length - 1;
    for (; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      const temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
  };
```

the shuffle button

```
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn}>
            <Text
              style={styles.btnText}
              onPress={this.shuffleDeck(this.state.deck)}
            >
              Shuffle
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

And finally the flatlist

```
        <View>
          <FlatList
            data={this.state.deck}
            numColumns={4}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <View style={styles.gridCard}>
                <Text style={styles.gridCardTxt}>{item.text}</Text>
              </View>
            )}
          />
        </View>
```

I only want to shuffle when the button is pressed, what am I missing?

---

I can now load the screen with array unshuffled, but now cannot update array when shuffle button is pressed;

per comments below here is updated code

```
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.btn}
        onPress={() => {
          this.setState({ deck: this.shuffleDeck(this.state.deck) });
        }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.btnText}>Shuffle</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the shuffle deck method?

Comment: @evolutionxbox oh yes I forget to mention that, the array is shown in order 0-9

Comment: May you make sure, using logging perhaps, that the shuffle method is not being called on load.

Comment: @evolutionxbox it is, but I don't understand why

Comment: What if you didn’t use a property but make it an actual method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your onPress to an arrow function:

```
onPress = {() => this.shuffleDeck(this.state.deck)}
```

Comment: That would do it. Otherwise the function is being called immediately.

Comment: Thank you. While it does fix, do I need to add more code for the list to refresh or show it shuffled?

Comment: @gSaenz not sure if you have solved this yet. If not, I can offer an explanation. In order to actually change the data in your state, you must call a method of a react component called setState. setState takes an object that is then merged with your previous state. It is better explained in the react docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly Going off of this, you must call setState in order to update it. I would change your onPress to:    onPress = {() => {
  this.setState({
    cards : this.shuffleDeck(this.state.deck)
  })
}}   -> Hope this helps

Comment: @NickD ah, yes, I try to use `setState` but in the shuffle function. I know is not the right place and also I try in the onPress but still doesn't fix the issue. The [touchableOpacity](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity) doc didn't have `setState`, why I didn't try in the beginning.  Also, side note, I moved onPress shuffle to touchable opacity instead of `<Text>`, i update above for reference.  Thought's why still doesn't work, i can open new question if needed.

Comment: as it turns out I was also missing `extraData={this.state}` prop in the flatlist.